# JSON - Schema: check fields in a nested structure only if another field has a certain value

Tags: json, jsonschema

In a nested JSON object, certain fields should only be required if another field has a certain value.
How can a JSON scheme be developed for this?

```
      {
        "kind": "new",
        "contact": {
          "mail": "foo@foo.de",
          "name": "foo",
          "street": "foo"
        }
      }
```

The "contact" object is not required if 'kind' has a value other than "new". The "contact" object may be included in this case. But it must not be checkedfor required values, only for their type like string....

If 'kind' has the value "new", the object "contact" is required and in the object "contact" only the field 'mail' is required. The other two fields "name" and "street" still have to be validated for their type so that they are both a string.

Comment: Think i have a solution. Will post it in the next hours :)

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html